# How can I rotate single object in the container?

Tags: c#, winforms, rotation

Hello I created a Rotation function to rotate the graphics.

However it rotates everything within the container object (my container is PictureBox).

this are my rotation funcs:

```
public void RotateGraphics(PaintEventArgs e, float angle, PointF loc)
{
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(loc.X, loc.Y);
    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
}
public void SetOrigin(PaintEventArgs e, float objWidth, float objHeight)
{
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-(objWidth / 2.0f), -(objHeight / 2.0f));
}
```

This is how I draw the object:

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), recP2.X, recP2.Y, elWidth, elHeight);
```

It works fine but my question is: How can I rotate only one Rectangle or whatever within the container?

Comment: how are you drawing that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the transformation beofore drawing the object you want the transfomration to apply on, and reset the transformation after that:

```
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, 10, 10, 20, 20);
    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(20);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 10, 30, 20, 20);
    e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
```

This way the rotation only applies to the second drawing command (red rectangle).